# How to catch a child procedure exception from parent function?

Tags: c#, exception, foreach

I have

```
public void ParentFunction()
{
   try
   {
      foreach (var item in someArray)
      {
         procedure1();
         procedure2();
         procedure3();
      }
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
      console.Writeline(exc.Message);
   }
}
```

In every procedure I have try-catch exception handling.
How can I catch any procedure's exception in ParentFunction? Basically, I need to skip foreach item to next one when any exception in any procedure is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for example using your parent class

```
public void ParentFunction()
{
   try
   {
      foreach (var item in someArray)
      {
         try 
         {
            procedure1();
            procedure2();
            procedure3();
         }
         catch(Exception exc)
         {
            continue;
         }

      }
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
      console.Writeline(exc.Message);
   }
}
```

Inside your procedures explicitly throw the exception, so for example in procedure1 you explicitly throw the specific exception.

```
throw new FaultException // Sample exception only
```

The try-catch inside your loop will catch this exception and just ignore it and proceed to next iteration.

But, I don't know why you are not handling exceptions properly and just ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
public void ParentFunction()
{
    foreach (var item in someArray)
    {
        if(!TryExecute(procedure1())
            continue;
        if(!TryExecute(procedure2())
            continue;

        TryExecute(procedure3());   
    }   
}

public bool TryExecute(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action.Invoke();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
      console.Writeline(exc.Message);
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you:

```
    public void ParentFunction()
    {
      try
      {
         foreach (var item in someArray)
         {
           //If an error occurred in flowing Try-Catch Skip
           // and foreach go to next item
           try
           {
               procedure1();
               procedure2();
               procedure3();
           }
           catch(Exception exc)
           {
                //Here you can Handle your procedures error
                console.Writeline(exc.Message);
           }
         }
      }
      catch(Exception exc)
      {
         console.Writeline(exc.Message);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you need info about a thrown exception in ParentFunction() you only have to throw exception from a child procedure and ParentFunction() will catch it.

In your question now, I assume that all you need is to make your procedure a boolean function, if returns true go to the next child function else use continue; . (If something goes wrong inside child_function instead of throw an exception, just return false.

```
public void ParentFunction()
{
   try
   {
      foreach (var item in someArray)
      {
         if( ! child_function1())
            continue;
         if( ! child_function1())
            continue;
         child_function3();
      }
   }
   catch(Exception exc)
   {
      console.Writeline(exc.Message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can initialize part of the object in a different method:

```
class Baseclass
{
    public virtual void callingbasefuntion()
    {
        throw new caughtexecption();
    }  
}

class Derivedclass : Baseclass
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            base.callingbasefuntion();
        }
        catch (caughtexecption)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

var object = new Derivedclass ();
object.callingbasefuntion();
```